# Using "In the last year"

Tags: tense

Which one is grammatically correct?

> "In the last year, I had the opportunity to.."

or

> " In the last year, I have had the opportunity to.."

That's because I've read you can't use past simple with "In the last year"

Answer (score 1):

Both of your example sentences are correct, it would be more a matter of style.
Your source is not correct, it is possible to the *simple past* with "***in the last year***"

> In **the** last year, I read 20 books, flew to Spain, and sat in mud. What did you do?

"***The***" is necessary when using "***in***".

> In **the** next year, I hope to write more, travel to Japan, and stay dry.

is possible

> In next year, I hope to write more, travel to Japan, and stay dry.

is not correct.

> In this, **the** last day before I leave,...

changes in construction to

> In this last day before I leave,...

An exception is

> **In the** next day...

is usually

> **On the** next day...

Comment: Do not use **in** before 'this’, 'last', and 'next' when saying when something happens:
▪ I got a letter from my sister this morning (NOT in this morning).
▪ I hope to go to Europe next summer (NOT in next summer).  _Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5th Ed._

Comment: @MvLog In this case, *in the last year* is part of a dependent, introductory clause that has no affect on the grammar of the independent clause that follows.