# the proper tense of “within the past…“

Tags: tense

> Within the past week, Europe **has** imposed tariffs on American motorcycles, bourbon, orange juice and other products.

> NASA calls these missions EVAs, Extra Vehicular Activities and two of them **were** completed within the past week.

I'm confused about which tense matches "within the past period of time".

I searched a few sentences containing the phrase "within the past period of time" and most of them use the present tense, which seems odd to me because there is a "past" in the context.

Yet some of them still use the past tense, I want to know why there can be two inconsistent usages of tense.

Comment: Do you know the "*present perfect*" tense? In the first sentence, "has imposed" is present perfect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "In the last year"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/179161/using-in-the-last-year)

Comment: @gotube Oh! Now I understand.